# Python & Selenium: How to wait until is text is present to continue?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I am trying to automate an extraction of stock prices in my broker website because yahoo and google finance have delays. But i need the code to wait for the 'home-broker' to be online so it can continue with scraping...

Here is my code:

```
expected = 'online'
while True:
    try:
       driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="spnStatusConexao"]').text == expected
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print('offline')
    else:
    print('online')
```

But, while testing it, it prints 'online' even when the homebroker displays 'offline' message.

I need to print 'offline' when the xpath text is equal to: offline . And to print 'online' when xpath text is equal to: online.

**EDIT:**

outter HTML:

```html
<span id="spnStatusConexao" hover="DV_bgConexao" class="StatusConexao online">online</span>
```

XPath:

```html
//*[@id="spnStatusConexao"]
```

Full XPath:

```html
/html/body/form/div[9]/div/div/p[2]/span
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`expected_conditions` in Python has a built in operation for this called `text_to_be_present_in_element`. The below code snippet will wait for the `span` element to contain the text `online`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.ID, "spnStatusConexao"), 'online'))
```

If this does not work, you can try invoking `WebDriverWait` on the `presence_of_element_located` and include the `text` in your XPath query:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@id='spnStatusConexao' and contains(text(),'online')]")))
```

Comment: There is no way i can predict how much time the page will load. When the page loads, it starts with offline message and after a while it changes to online.  This will make my code proceed when the offline changes to online or is just expecting a online message when page loads? Sorry if i'm confusing...

Comment: Got: selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: If the page starts with 'offline' message, you want to wait until the text says 'online'. Applying `WebDriverWait` here will wait until the element located by `//*[@id='spnStatusConexao']` displays the 'online' text -- it will only wait as long as it needs to. After this `WebDriverWait` is complete, you can continue scraping the page. If you are seeing a `TimeoutException`, either the 'online' text did not appear within 10 seconds, or the element locator is not correct. You can try changing `WebDriverWait(driver, 10)` to `WebDriverWait(driver, 60)` and see if that helps.

Comment: @GuilhermeAlmeidaC.Machado You do not need to predict exactly how long the page will take to load. If you call `WebDriverWait(driver, 100)`, the driver will not wait 100 seconds every time. It will wait *up to* 100 seconds, but if the page loads in 5 seconds then the code will continue after 5 seconds.

Comment: OK, will try these changes. Thanks ofr the help!

Comment: @GuilhermeAlmeidaC.Machado No problem, please report back here with any errors you still encounter. It may be helpful to post the HTML for the element that shows the 'offline' / 'online' text so we can verify the locator is correct as well.

Comment: So i tried with WebDriverWait(driver, 400), waited for the offline to turn online but the print('online') i put after your line of code was never printed. I edited my question with the outter HTML where offline/online appears, added xpath and full xpath as well

Comment: @GuilhermeAlmeidaC.Machado Thanks for the update -- when you tried with 400 seconds, what did the web page look like? Was the page actually still loading & showing 'offline', or did the 'online' text already appear, and the code just did not detect it?

Comment: The page loaded on aprox. 30 seconds, displaying offline message, and after more 50 sec. the online message appeared, but after the 400 was complete, i got TimeoutException –

Comment: @GuilhermeAlmeidaC.Machado It sounds to me like the `WebDriverWait` was not correctly detecting the 'online' text, most likely due to an invalid locator. I updated my answer with a 2nd option where `contains(text(), 'online)'` is included in the XPath query which might work. However, if that does not work, then there is something else on the page interfering with the locator -- there may be an `iframe` element higher up in the DOM which would need to be switched to before interacting with the page.

Comment: IT WORKED! Many Thanks Christine. I added a `print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='spnStatusConexao']").text)` after the new line you sent and it printed online as soon as the system got online. Now i will proceed with the rest of scrapping!

Comment: i have a questio:, how can i add a loop for when the element is not found on given time, make driver.refresh()?

Comment: Solved by: except TimeoutException:

Comment: Yes that's correct, you can `try` / `except TimeoutException` to handle the scenario in a loop and ignore the exception thrown.